# Why does the `of_find_compatible_node` function have two definitions in `/kernel/include/linux/of.h`, and how is the definition chosen?

Tags: linux

The function `of_find_compatible_node` has two definition. One is

```
static online struct device_node *of_find_compatible_node(struct device_node *from,const char *type, const char *compatible)
```

another is

```
extern struct device_node *of_find_compatible_node(struct device_node *from,const char *type, const char *compatible)
```

These functions are defined the same.I know the keyword `static online` and `extern`,but I don't understand :

1. When I use the function，what does the compiler choose?
2. Why are two functions not redefined?

---

In `base.c` and `include<of.h>`， there appears to be a re-definition of `struct_device_node *of_find_comatible_node(struct device_node *from,const char *type,const char *compatible)`.  Why?  I think it causes redefinition when linking.

Comment: I see [a declaration](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.9/include/linux/of.h#L271) and [a definition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.9/include/linux/of.h#L705), not two definitions.

Comment: Sorry，I don't notice.```extern```is declaration.But why declaration a same function.If I want definition it in other file,when I use it，there's redefinition.  Also in ```of.h``` this function is defined ```return NULL```.Is error,the function is to find compatible.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common pattern in kernel headers (and not just there). If you take a closer look at the file (or use an editor that does code folding), you can notice that both lines are inside conditional compilation blocks, like this:

```c
#ifdef CONFIG_OF
extern struct device_node *of_find_compatible_node(struct device_node *from,
    const char *type, const char *compat);
#else /* CONFIG_OF */
static inline struct device_node *of_find_compatible_node(
                        struct device_node *from,
                        const char *type,
                        const char *compat)
{
    return NULL;
}
#endif
```

Thus if `CONFIG_OF` is enabled, the former part gets compiled in and serves as a declaration of the function, whose real definition is placed in some `.c` file. If the kernel is configured without `CONFIG_OF`, the `#else` branch will be used, supplying a dummy no-op implementation of the function so that the rest of the kernel still compiles correctly.

The dummy implementation is also `static inline`, allowing the compiler to just replace calls to it by a constant `NULL` value and likely optimize whole code paths away, decreasing code size and eliminating runtime overhead.

Comment: Thanks,I understand.